# create and edit view table?

Tags: sql

How to create a view with the name "changedata" to see the full name of all employees, salary, department name and the name of the region and allows edit of data from the table s_emp view?

```
create view change as 
SELECT a.last_name||','||a.first_name as "Nombre", 
       a.salary as "Salary", b.name"Department", 
       c.name as "Region Name"
FROM s_emp a, s_dept b, s_region c
WHERE a.dept_id = b.id AND b.region_id = c.id
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the structure of the table(s).

Comment: What's your RDBMS and what's the point of the code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Two options.

1. Include all the columns you want to be made editable, and make sure the view is updateable (I think in this case you'd at least need unique constraints on s_dept.id and s_region.id). Note that this will still not allow derived data to be edited (e.g. your "Nombre", "Department" and "Region Name" columns will not be editable).
2. Create INSTEAD OF triggers to handle inserts, updates and/or deletes on the view.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is specific to Oracle.